# Any info on why Media Player appears to block UI input for about 30 seconds

Tags: uwp

I'm running a short video in my UWP app while a number of other tasks are completing in the background.  If the user doesn't want to watch the video, there is a "Skip Video" button for them.  However, the button doesn't become active for about 30 seconds into the video.

I thought perhaps it was my background tasks blocking the UI, but they're complete in 5-7 seconds.  I also thought perhaps it was the video loading that was causing the problem, but it's only 3 minutes long so I don't think it would take that long to buffer in.

Here is the XAML I'm using for the page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Cgs.Ux.Views.MainMenu"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Cgs.Ux"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:userControls="using:Cgs.Ux.UserControls"
    xmlns:help="using:Cgs.Ux.UserControls.Help"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <RelativePanel RequestedTheme="Light">
        <Image Source="{x:Bind Vm.PlainBackgroundImage, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
               Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Viewbox RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{x:Bind Vm.BackgroundImage, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
                       RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                       Height="1080" Width="1920" Opacity=".5"/>
                <!--Media Player-->
                <MediaPlayerElement
                    Name="MediaSimple"
                    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Videos/Transfer Items Alpha 2.mp4"
                    Width="1920" Height="1080" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                </MediaPlayerElement>
                <Button
                    Name="SkipVideo"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="30"
                    Content="Skip Video" Height="100" Width="400" Background="White"
                    Visibility="{x:Bind Vm.SkipVideoVisible, Mode=OneWay}"
                    PointerEntered="OnPointerEntered"
                    Click="{x:Bind Vm.SkipVideo}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
        <ProgressRing
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
            Width="100" Height="100" Foreground="NavajoWhite" IsActive="{x:Bind Vm.IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

Here is the relevant code behind:

```
public void PlayMedia()
{
    MediaSimple.MediaPlayer.Play();
    MediaSimple.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

public void SkipVideo()
{
    View.StopVideo();
    _introVideoFinished = true;
    if (_soloGameLoaded && _introVideoFinished) GotoGame();
}

private void OnPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Pointer Entered");
}
```

I would expect that the button should be available immediately, or almost immediately.

Comment: Your code was incomplete. Please provide a [mcve] for more diagnostic.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include more of the code.  The OnPointerEntered event handler is only there to identify when the button becomes active.

Comment: Sorry, I could not help you more. You still did not provide a [mcve]. I tried to copy your code into my new blank project to test. But there're many errors. I even cannot debug it. If you want to get help from community member, you need to improve your question. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) at first.

Comment: I've never had to provide a fully working project here before.  I didn't realize that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to create a standalone project to replicate the problem.  Sadly, my standalone projects all worked perfectly.  The difference between my standalone project and my failing project was the background tasks that I was launching while the video was starting up.

My initial idea that the background tasks were blocking the UI was on target.  I modified the background tasks to run on a separate thread and the media player and skip video buttons worked perfectly.

After moving the background tasks to their own thread, the app started failing on Marshalling errors because the background task was trying to talk to the UI.  This explained why the background task was blocking the UI for up to 30 seconds, when I expected it to complete in 5-7 seconds.

The moral of the story, don't run background tasks on your UI thread and expect your UI to behave properly.